# i4gl :- SQL statement error number -201

Tags: informix

In i4gl  IDE I am facing this exception in a report program for printing deductions from pay for all personnel of a particular category.

This program is working fine for employees of one category but fails in case of employees of other category.

Please suggest a solution.Thanking in anticipation.

I have mentioned the lines of code where error message points fingers to and also the error message below:

```
let _stmt = "select * from pay_slip where per_no = '",r_hist.per_no ,
            "' and yrmn = '",_yrmn,"' and govt_str ='", __hdr clipped,"'"
prepare prep_stmt from _stmt
execute prep_stmt into r_slip.*
```

error message:

```
Program stopped at "DED_SUM_EX.4gl", line number 109.
SQL statement error number -201.
A syntax error has occurred.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

- DISPLAY your SQL statement before running it.
- Run the SQL statement in DB-Access to see what is going on, the error will be more explicit.

Comment: used the display statement to view the sql statement and found that one of the strings in query had inverted comma that was causing the statement to fail..made some changes to database and everything is fine now..thanks for the suggestion...